# How to use vi to batch match characters and paste after the matched characters

Tags: vimrc, gvim, delimiter-matching

I want to use vi to quickly edit text.

there is the format on lines m to n of the file.

```
    .lut_da_25,
    .abc_we23,
    ...
    .yy_ewe,
```

I want to edit the above lines to the following

```
    .lut_da_25(lut_da_25),
    .adc_we23(adc_we23),
    ...
    .yy_ewe(yy_ewe),
```

is there a quick method in vi to achieve the above functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like

```
%substitute/\.\(\w\+\)/&(\1)/
```

Would do it. Assumptions: comma is not a “word” character (?), no more than one record per line.

Comment: this answer helps me a lot.